# Display Images in orginal view in landscape or portrait not stretch

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to display many images in a container but if the image is landscape it's not bad but if the image is **portrait** when I insert it, it display **stretched**. it show every picture landscape, it's not beautiful. I want to show each images as it's original orientation and max height of the container is 415px.
this is my output:
[landscape image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WAEP.png)
[portrait image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acNvb.png)
please help this is my code.

```
<li class="main-image-set ">
    <a href="<?=get_image($product['image_one']);?>" class="thumbnail"  style="padding: 3px; width: 100%; max-height: 520px; height: auto;">
        <img src="<?=get_image($product['image_one']);?>" style="height: 414px"  >
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Try `background-size: auto;` in css or `background-size: contain;` -  scales the image as large as possible without cropping or stretching the image.

Comment: Thanks @dalelandry but it's not useful for my work.

Answer (score 1):

First note: A portrait image will never fill the same space as a horizontal image without skewing the aspect ratio of the image, which is what you are seeing in your code/example.

Assuming the desired affect is to have them appear the "same size" you'll end up with an image item that is in a square. In your example `.max-image-set`

If you style a portrait and landscape with the same max-height your portrait image will have whitespace on the left and right side of it. Transversely if you style them with the same max-width you will have whitespace above and below a landscape image. (assuming they are in a square, and the desired affect is to have them appear the "same size")

```
.main-image-set a {
    display: flex; /* for alignment */
    justify-content: center; /* horizontally align portrait image */
    align-items: center; /* vertically align landscape image */


    /** fixed width, creates a square for our image to live */
    width: 414px;
    height: 414px;
    /* Could be styles with a responsive technique a like aspect ratio prop, but that is outside the scope of here */

    background-color: #eee; /* so you can see the "square", for demo purposes */
}

.main-image-set img {
    width: auto; /* to counter any width attributes and allow intrinsic image width */
    height: auto; /* to counter any height attributes and allow intrinsic height */
    max-width: 100%; /* scale with the parent element width */
    max-height: 100%; /* scale with the parent element height */
}
```

This will result in something like this...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dear @dylanjameswagner I want how to do it

> If you style a portrait and landscape with the same max-height your portrait image will have whitespace on the left and right side of it.

I tried many time but I can't, I want it show me like this [image]

as on image look I want to display portrait images on center of the frame which on both side left and right have a white space but If Images is landscape it showed me inside entire of the frame which is not display white space of both sides.

Comment: If you use the info from my answer above but set the width to a larger pixel value. Looks like your image is 16:9 ratio which would be 736px x 414px